# Desining a database for word frequency and text analysis

Tags: database, database-design, cpu-word, analysis, word-frequency

I have a bunch of articles, on which I want to do word frequency and trend analysis.

The articles are tagged with date, author, theme and subject. I want to use these tags to slice the data so that I can get the most common words used for a specific author (or group of authors), theme(s) or subject(s). Overall and over time (trend).

How would I design this database (relational or other) or should I create a data cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rizzoma.com made this with couchDB (noSQL) and Sphinx (fulltext search engine).
You can try to make it in another way, if you want, or test existing solution and repeat it.

Comment: If I chose to do this with a relational database I'd 

  1. add a table for articles
  2. add a table for each type of tag
  3. add connection tables between tag tables and the article table
  4. create indexes for each relation using Sphinx
  5. Do some magic with Sphinx to get word frequencies

Comment: I don't see any reason to ignore nosql database engines in your case. You should research them too. I can be wrong, but I haven't mentioned why should be relation engines used for this task.

Comment: Only because I don't have any experience with nosql databases. How would I store the data in a noSQL database?

Comment: They are document-based. You are no more limited with row-column ideology.